# Eclipseで１つのフォルダ内だけがファイルが表示されない

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipseで、Javaの開発をしています。

１年以上使っていたEclipseの開いたままのプロジェクトが、
あるとき、パソコンのパージョンアップでパソコンが再起動されました。

その後、Eclipseを起動したのですが、パッケージ・エクスプローラに
ファイルが表示されていなかったり、フォルダが無くなっていたりした状態でプロジェクトが開きました。

直ぐにリフレッシュしたのですが、余計にひどくなり、
各種ソースフォルダや、ビルド後のclassが入るはずのフォルダも
無いものが存在したり、参照ライブラリー内のライブララリも１０個以上あったのが３個になってしまいました。

それで、一からフォルダを作り、そこにファイルを入れたりして、
フォルダ構成は復活させ、ファイルもその中に表示されるように戻しました。

しかし、復活後はフォルダ内にjarファイルが表示されていたのですが、
現在は表示されない状態になってしまいました。

色々、Eclipseでそのフォルダの設定を変えたりしたのですが、変わらず。
ネットでずっと調べていたのですが、これについての記述は見つからず。

そこで、ここでご質問させて頂きたく、この書き込みをさせて頂きました。

作っているもの

- Linuxサーバー上で稼働するJavaアプリ

環境

- Windows10

[image: これが、そのフォルダです]

Comment: 「参照ライブラリー」の下に、そのjarは表示されていますか？もし表示されているならそれが本来の状態ではないかと思います。つまり、今回の件が発生する前から表示されていなかったのではないかと。

Answer (score 1):

- (チームで開発されているように見受けられますので、)ちゃんと正しい状態になっているかどうか周りの詳しい方に確認してもらうべきでしょう
- 気にされている箇所が問題の原因では無いかもしれません(エクスプローラーで該当ディレクトリを開くと、本当にjarファイルは入っているのか？など色々と分からない)

という前置きをした上で…

質問中にあるアイコンは、Eclipse上でビルドパスとして設定したディレクトリに付与されるものです。
.java ファイルやリソースファイルを置いておくディレクトリです。

この設定を削除するには、パッケージエクスプローラ(キャプチャ画像で示されているタブですね)でプロジェクトを右クリックし `Properties(プロパティ)` を選択、表示されたダイアログで
`Java Build Path` メニューの `Source` タブから `WEB-INF/lib` を選択し `Remove` ボタンを押せばよいです。

[image: プロパティダイアログ]

Comment: 一人で開発しています（ですので、約１年で５０００ファイル程度しか作成していません）。
eclipseでの初めての開発です。
無事に、開発したものは、バグもなく、稼働しておりますが、仕様変更をしている最中でしたので、このトラブルは痛い状態です。
約1年前に設定できたまま、ずっと使い続けてきたのですが、一年前にどうやって設定したかは手さぐりであちこち設定したので、設定手順書を作らなかったのが、敗因です。

WEB-INF/libの中には、書いている通り、jarが多数入っています。
ですので、それが表示されないから、ご質問しているということになります。
※ファイルが何も入って無ければ、当然、フォルダの中身は表示されませんので。

尚、教えて頂いた手順で、WEB-INF/libを削除できました。
ありがとうございます。

ですが、普通のフォルダとしても、もうEclipseが、プロジェクト内に作成できないように「完了」ボタンが押せない状態なので、
今度は、WEB-INF/lib フォルダをパッケージ・エクスプローラーに表示させる方法を探しています。

前の WEB-INF/lib は、ビルド対象のJava用ソースフォルダにしてしまったことが原因とわかりました。

Comment: プロジェクトがバージョン管理されているようでしたので複数人開発であると考えました。お一人であるということはリポジトリの状態について分かっていると思われるので、一旦現状を破棄してリポジトリからチェックアウトしセットアップし直すのが近道ではないでしょうか。

Comment: バックアップ及び、デグレ時に戻せるように、念の為、バージョン管理をしておりました。さらに、別のサーバーへソースを定期的に、手でコピーしてのバックアップもしており、この開発PC,CVS,バックアップ用サーバーの３重にしていました。これは、昔からの癖で、一度作成した文書やソースは、物理的削除をしない（削除したいもの専用のサーバーへ移動させ保存）。ソースもドキュメントも、多数か所でバックアップを取るようにしています。

Comment: ご指示の様にしてみます。実は、何もかも手さぐりで、且、開発量が多く、一年間全く一日も休みがなく、５０００ファイル程開発していたので（サーバーでは運よくバグもなく、多数のユーザー様に使用されていますので、安心しきっていたバチですね、開発者なら、開発手順や設定手順書を作成するのが正常な人です）、お恥ずかしいのですが、リポジトリの構造もわからないのですが、これがEclipseやリポジトリを理解するチャンスと考え、トライします。